# How to round a data frame in R which have some non-numeric variables?

Tags: r

I got some decimals in 'mydata2'. So, I want to round only numeric variables in mydata2. I have tried some methods like 'use purrr' or 'dplyr' etcs but I couldn't get it. How to I get it?

```
   setwd("D:/데이터 사이언스/새 폴더") 
    mydata <- read.csv("Remote Learning.csv", header = TRUE) 
    mydata 
    
    mydata2 <- aggregate(학업.기여도~학교.유형 , mydata, mean)
    
    library(ggplot2) 
    
    ggplot(data=mydata2, aes(x = 학교.유형, y = 학업.기여도, fill = 학교.유형)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(color = 학교.유형))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if the variables are numeric indeed (you have to rename your columns I suppose as there are some limitations for column names in R):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::select(col1 = 1, col2 = 2) %>% # enter all the columns you have and some simple names without special characters
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(., 0))
```

Comment: I have do that, but I got the message that " Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function" "

Comment: can you supply a few demo lines for your data in the question please? Maybe print out the header?

Comment: Not sure about your column names => may try to convert them wo simple words? (like col1, col2... just to run the test and see if the problem stems from the special characters)

Comment: @JayChoi just included a line that changes the name of the first 2 columns - please increase according you your data.frame

Comment: my heads are  '연령대 ',  '학교.유형', '원격.수업.방식' ,'학업.기여도' ,'만족도'. I will set each heads as 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'.  I am working with B&D.

Comment: make sure you alter all the tmes of the dataframe. In my example the line would be   dplyr::select(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5)

Comment: So, I changed to
setwd("D:/데이터 사이언스/새 폴더") 
mydata <- read.csv("Remote Learning.csv", header = TRUE) 
mydata 


aggregate(B~D , mydata, mean) 
mydata2 <- aggregate(B~D , mydata, mean)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::select(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5) %>% # enter all the columns you have and some simple names without special characters
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(., 0))

Comment: But I got messages that > aggregate(B~D , mydata, mean)   D  B
1 1 NA
2 2 NA
3 3 NA
4 4 NA
5 5 NA
 In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: you can alter the name only in the last part - keep your aggregates like they are. Then between ggplot and aggregate perform this (for 4 columns): mydata2  <- mydata2 %>% 
  dplyr::select(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(., 0))

Comment: if mydata2 has 5 columns do this AFTER your aggregate:  mydata2 <- mydata2 %>% dplyr::select(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5) %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(., 0))

Comment: I thoroughly solved it with your methods. I have started study R just a few days ago, and also I am not good at English, so I spent so much time to solve this problem but I couldn't before today. I really appreciate about your help. Thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome - if possible accept or upvote my answer so it appears solved for everyone! thx